# PHP move_uploaded_file yet another not working

Tags: php, upload

I really can't figure this one out, just got a basic upload script but the file wont upload.

```
Form 
 => enctype is set

print_r($_FILES['Product_Thumb']) 
 => [Product_Thumb] 
  => Array ( 
      [name] => prototype.js 
      [type] => application/x-javascript 
      [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpXzL6CT 
      [error] => 0 
      [size] => 139854 ))
```

I did set the permissons (-R) to 777 on the upload folder. 
Changed the owner:group to www-data:www-data.
Mkdir works on the exact path I used for the upload file.
Tried different files, tried another folder, hardcoded the destination filepath, still doesnt work.

I see the file in /var/tmp/ but the moving is just not working, no error nothing at all.

Am I really overlooking something?

Thanx in advance!

=======================================================================
Debug output:

Debug: tmp file:/tmp/phpgYOo9a

Debug: target directory: /var/www/clubgevoel/public/img/producten/

Debug: real target: /var/www/clubgevoel/public/img/producten

Debug: source readable:

Debug: target is_dir: yes

Debug: target writable: yes

Debug: move: bool(false)

Comment: you need to show us the code you're using to move the file

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Product_Thumb']['tmp_name'], '/var/www/clubgevoel/public/img/producten/tralalala.jpg');
\r\n
also tried:

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Product_Thumb']['tmp_name'], '/var/www/clubgevoel/public/img/producten/' . $_FILES['Product_Thumb']['name']);

also tried:


move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Product_Thumb']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'clubgevoel/public/img/producten/2.jpg');


mkdir works on this path:


$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'clubgevoel/public/img/producten/makemeadir'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Debug: tmp file:/tmp/phpgYOo9a

Debug: target directory: /var/www/clubgevoel/public/img/producten/

Debug: real target: /var/www/clubgevoel/public/img/producten

Debug: source readable:

Debug: target is_dir: yes

Debug: target writable: yes

Debug: move: bool(false)

Comment: seems the source isnt readable, any ideas for this 1?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the additional information (instead of posting it as an *answer*)

Answer (score 0):

Full file quota on the server?

Comment: You mean in the tmp dir or diskspace?

Free space enough, server is an Ubuntu 9 with apache2 en php5.
Also removed all the files from /var/tmp to see if that helped, no it didnt :)

Comment: does simple copy() method work?

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded_file should issue a warning if it fails(i.e. returns false). Make sure to test the uploading script with display_errors to On an error_reporting to ALL, like this:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

error_reporting(-1);//or error_reporting(E_ALL); (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

These lines should be placed before anything else in your script. This way you could at least discover the reason for the error

Comment: gives me absolutely no errors or warnings at: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Product_Thumb']['tmp_name'], '/var/www/clubgevoel/public/img/producten/tralalala.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

i guess y are using ablolute path as destination.Try the relative one

Comment: when I use: S_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'public/img/producten/' . $_FILES['Product_Thumb']['name'] still not uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add more debug output.... What does

```
// "also tried: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Product_Thumb']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/clubgevoel/public/img/producten/2.jpg');"
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$targetDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/clubgevoel/public/img/producten/';
$realTargetDir = realpath($targetDir);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo '<pre>Debug: tmp file:', htmlspecialchars($_FILES['Product_Thumb']['tmp_name']), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: target directory: ', htmlspecialchars($targetDir), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: real target: ', htmlspecialchars($realTargetDir), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: source readable: ', is_readable($_FILES['Product_Thumb']['tmp_name']), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: target is_dir: ', is_dir($targetDir) ? 'yes':'no', "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: target writable: ', is_writeable($targetDir) ? 'yes':'no', "</pre>\n";

$b = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Product_Thumb']['tmp_name'], $targetDir. '2.jpg');
echo '<pre>Debug: move: '; var_dump($b); echo "</pre>\n";
```

print?