# move_uploaded_file oddness: "File was not able to be uploaded properly"

Tags: php

I have looked through about 5 or so questions that are like this and none have solved my issue. Here is the the one that most the most helpful but still did not solve it [PHP move_uploaded_file yet another not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198501/php-move-uploaded-file-yet-another-not-working).

Here is the code in question along with the debug code at the top.

```
$tempPath = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ];    
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$uploadPath = storage_path() . '/uploads/' . 'test' . '.csv';
$targetDir = storage_path() . '/uploads/';
$realTargetDir = realpath($targetDir);

echo '<pre>Debug: tmp file:', htmlspecialchars($tempPath), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: target directory: ', htmlspecialchars($targetDir), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: real target: ', htmlspecialchars($realTargetDir), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: source readable: ', is_readable($tempPath), "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: target is_dir: ', is_dir($targetDir) ? 'yes':'no', "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: target writable: ', is_writeable($targetDir) ? 'yes':'no', "</pre>\n";

if(!move_uploaded_file( $tempPath, $uploadPath )) {
    dd("File was not able to be uploaded properly.");
}
```

This outputs the following.

```
Debug: tmp file:/tmp/phpeFIjWc
Debug: target directory: /var/www/default/api/orgsync/app/storage/uploads/
Debug: real target: /var/www/default/api/orgsync/app/storage/uploads
Debug: source readable: 1
Debug: target is_dir: yes
Debug: target writable: yes
string 'File was not able to be uploaded properly.' (length=42)
```

To my understanding this is exactly what I want. I have a readable file and a writable directory. $_FILES['file']['error'] also spits out a 0 at me.

The files are all owned by the www-data user and group who I have checked is set at the user and group in my httpd.conf file.

```
 User www-data
 Group www-data
```

I am really at a loss of what step I should even take next to debug this. This is on a vagrant box if that makes any difference.

Mount Points as requested my MrTux:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                      18618236   3413824  14258648  20% /
tmpfs                   380120         0    380120   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               495844     34543    435701   8% /boot
WCRzK17j3F03         125032444 112697476  12334968  91% /var/www
vagrant              125032444 112697476  12334968  91% /vagrant
tmp_vagrant-puppet-3_manifests
                     125032444 112697476  12334968  91% /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests
tmp_vagrant-puppet-3_modules-0
                     125032444 112697476  12334968  91% /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0
```

Comment: Are /tmp and /var/www/default/api/orgsync/app/storage/uploads on the same mountpoint?

Comment: MrTux: added in mount points which show they are at different mount points. I am not positive how to remedy the issue though. I guess i could change where the tmp files get uploaded to from PHP but I am not sure if this is an optimal solution.

Comment: You don't appear to have defined `$tempPath`...

Comment: You are correct let me fix that I pasted in some old debug code. The output was run again and was the same just to ensure.

Comment: Can you go and check what `var_dump(is_uploaded_file($tempPath));` reports?

Comment: CBroe: it is returning false. however file_exists returns true.

Comment: OK, if `is_uploaded_file` returns false, then that’s your real issue here – because `move_uploaded_file` performs the same check, and refuses to do anything and only returns false if it has come to the conclusion that the file in question has not actually originated in an HTTP file upload received by PHP …

Comment: CBroe just got to that conclusion. Would not have figured it out without you. If you want to post the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `is_uploaded_file` returns false, that’s where the real issue lies here – because `move_uploaded_file` performs the same check, and refuses to do anything and only returns false if it has come to the conclusion that the file in question has not actually originated in an HTTP file upload received by PHP.

So go you must … and figure out why that path is not the path to an actual uploaded temp file.

Comment: @mschuett, your comment sounded like you found the issue already – let us know what exactly it was please, that could add a little more to this otherwise rather meager answer.

Comment: Ok so the issue was I was working with another library and didn't realize that it was moving where the tmp file was uploaded. Although I was getting the proper location returned to me and the file existed I could no longer move it with move_uploaded_file. I which the function call to rename and everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_files()` requires a full path + filename (or at LEAST a filename). You're providing ONLY a path.

e.g.

```
move_uploaded_files($source, '/upload/destination/'); //invalid
move_uploaded_files($source, '/upload/destination/foo.txt'); //VALID
                    you MUST provide a filename---^^^^^^^
```

Getting a `0` for your `['error']` means that the file was upload successfully - you're just not moving it correctly.

Comment: I had tried this before and just appended dummy.txt to the end of $uploadPath in my file and it is still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was I was working with another library and didn't realize that it was moving where the tmp file was uploaded. Although I was getting the proper location returned to me and the file existed I could no longer move it with move_uploaded_file. I which the function call to rename and everything worked great.